# Best Practice for Managing WebSocket Connections in a Chat Application for Displaying Real-Time Messages in Chat Room List

Tags: redis, spring-webflux, chat

I'm currently developing a chat application using Spring WebFlux, Redis, and MongoDB. The application features a chat room list where users can see all the chat rooms they belong to, along with the most recent message from each room. My challenge is figuring out the optimal timing and method for associating user sessions with their respective chat rooms to display real-time messages in the chat room list, even before a user enters any specific chat room.

Here is how I'm managing sessions and connections:

User IDs and session objects are mapped in-memory.

User IDs to session IDs, as well as room IDs to session IDs, are stored and managed in Redis.

When a new message arrives in any chat room, I want this message to be displayed as the latest message in the chat room list view. However, I'm unsure about when and how to best establish these connections. The straightforward approach I'm considering is to connect a user's session to all chat rooms they belong to as soon as they view the chat room list. This approach seems inefficient and possibly not the standard practice.

My questions are:

1. What is the best practice for managing WebSocket connections in such scenarios to update the chat room list with real-time messages efficiently?
2. Should the user's session be linked to the chat rooms they belong to at a specific moment, such as when the chat room list is viewed, or is there a better strategy to handle this?
3. Are there any efficient patterns or strategies commonly adopted in real-time chat applications to minimize server load while providing a seamless user experience?

Any advice or insights on how to architect this part of the application would be greatly appreciated. I'm especially interested in understanding the typical approaches used in the industry for similar real-time message display functionalities in chat applications.